# How to change back bar button's width of a UINavigationController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, titleview, backbarbuttonitem

I have two table view controllers. Say **TableViewController1** and **TableViewController2**.

I push **TableViewController2** when someone clicks on the **TableViewController1**'s cell.

I set the **TableViewController1**'s clicked cell's value as the **TableViewController2**'s back bar button's title value.

According to the length of the **TableViewController1** cell's string, the back bar button's length also get changing.

Is it possible to fix the width of the back bar button? I really need this, because I want to capture the tap events of the **TableViewController2** navigation bar's *titleView*.

Back bar button's width affects the *titleView*'s width. So I can not find the bounds of the *titleView*. Or is there any other way to find the bounds value of a titleView of Navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to fix the width of the back bar button?

As far as I know you can not edit this button.

Subclassing it would be the way to go, or you might want to truncate the title from the previous viewController. Alternatively you might want to replace with with a normal *UIBarButtonItem* like so:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @”shortTitle.”;

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                            target:nil
                            action:nil];

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];
 }
```