# iOS UINavigationBar Button item width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Am trying to create an UINavigationBar that look like the one in Facebook app. actually am stack at customizing  UINavigationBar back button width!

Any idea, tips or helps please ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change back bar button's width of a UINavigationController in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824220/how-to-change-back-bar-buttons-width-of-a-uinavigationcontroller-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

The button itself has a set width. You could build a custom toolbar and implement functionality that makes it look like a standard navigation bar though. That's probably your best option for this.